# Order by slow on joined large table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have 3 large table around 1 table have 1,000,000 rows other 2 have 500,000 rows.

When I use ORDER BY in query it takes 15 seconds (without ORDER BY 0.001s).

I already try add index on invoice.created_at and invoice.invoice_id
But still take a lot of time.

```
SELECT 
    `i`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ii.item_id SEPARATOR ',') AS item_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT it.transaction_id SEPARATOR ',') AS transactions,
    SUM(DISTINCT IF(ii.status = 1, ii.subtotal, 0)) AS subtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT it.subtotal) AS total_paid_amount,
    SUM(DISTINCT it.additional_fee) AS total_additional_fee_amount,
    SUM(ii.quantity) AS total_quantity,
    (total_amount - SUM(DISTINCT COALESCE(it.amount, 0))) AS total_balance
FROM
    `invoices` `i`

    LEFT JOIN
        `invoices_items` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`invoice_id`
    LEFT JOIN
        `invoices_transactions` `it` ON `it`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`invoice_id`
            AND `it`.`process_status` = 1
            AND `it`.`status` = 1
WHERE
    `i`.`status` = '1'

GROUP BY `i`.`invoice_id`
ORDER BY `i`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Query with EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                    | key        | key_len | ref                          | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i    | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,customer_id,code,invoice_id_2,created_at | PRIMARY    | 4       | NULL                         | 473309 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ii   | NULL       | ref   | invoice_id                                       | invoice_id | 5       | test.i.invoice_id |      2 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | it   | NULL       | ref   | invoice_id,status                                | invoice_id | 5       | test.i.invoice_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I try to remove SUM ,GROUP_CONCAT and WHERE CASE,
But still need 10 sec

```
SELECT 
    `i`.*
FROM
    `invoices` `i`
        LEFT JOIN
    `invoices_items` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`invoice_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `invoices_transactions` `it` ON `it`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`invoice_id`

GROUP BY `i`.`invoice_id`
ORDER BY `i`.`created_at` DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `invoice_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `warehouse_id` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_type` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C',
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_no` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_amount` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_cost` deimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_type` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `remark` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i,
  `payment_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int NOT NULL,
  `confirmed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `invoice_id_2` (`invoice_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=513697 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_i;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices_items` (
  `item_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `variant_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int DEFAULT '1',
  `unit_price` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `StockoutDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReturnDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Return_StockLocationID` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `priority` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
  KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`),
  KEY `quantity` (`quantity`),
  KEY `unit_price` (`unit_price`),
  KEY `subtotal` (`subtotal`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `priority` (`priority`),
  KEY `variant_id_2` (`variant_id`,`quantity`),
  KEY `variant_id_3` (`variant_id`,`name`,`quantity`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `StockoutDate` (`StockoutDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1200951 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_i;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices_transactions` (
  `transaction_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_rate` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_fee` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` deimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `process_status` int DEFAULT '1',
  `remark` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_status` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_i DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `CreatedByID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedByID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
  KEY `payment_status` (`payment_status`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `amount` (`amount`),
  KEY `additional_fee` (`additional_fee`),
  KEY `subtotal` (`subtotal`),
  KEY `transaction_id` (`transaction_id`,`amount`,`additional_fee`,`subtotal`),
  KEY `invoice_id_2` (`invoice_id`,`process_status`,`status`),
  KEY `process_status` (`process_status`),
  KEY `transaction_id_2` (`transaction_id`,`invoice_id`,`amount`,`additional_fee`,`subtotal`,`process_status`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=543606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_i;
```

Comment: I cannot think of a situation where `SUM(DISTINCT)` would be correct I I have never used it for anything real.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Mysql seems to use the primary key for the invoice table instead of invoice_id_2 index. Have you tried to use `use index` or `force index` to make mysql use invoice_id_2 instead?

Comment: How much time take a simple query with order and limit without joins? 
 `SELECT i.* FROM  invoices i ORDER BY i.created_at DESC LIMIT 50`

Comment: after I join table without SUM and where ,It rise to around 6~8sec
SELECT `i` . *
FROM `invoices` `i`
LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`invoice_id`
GROUP BY `i`.`invoice_id`
ORDER BY `i`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 50

Comment: I got same result using force index/use index

Comment: It take 0.001sec. SELECT i.* FROM invoices i ORDER BY i.created_at DESC LIMIT 50

Comment: @apple_w - 0.001 sec sounds like you have the Query cache turned on.  Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` for timing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the 50 invoices *first*, then reach for the rest of the stuff:

```
SELECT ... (all the current stuff)
    FROM ( SELECT invoice_id
               FROM invoices
               WHERE status = 1
               ORDER BY created_at DESC
               LIMIT 50
         ) AS ids
    JOIN invoices AS i USING(invoice_id)
    LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
    LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
    GROUP BY invoice_id
    ORDER BY created_id DESC
```

These composite indexes may help:

```
i:  (status, created_at, invoice_id)
it:  (status, process_status, invoice_id)
ii:  (invoice_id, quantity, subtotal, status, item_id)
```

Redundant index:

```
KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`)  -- since this is the prefix of others
```

Because of `PRIMARY KEY(transaction_id)`, the keys starting with `transaction_id` are redundant.

Summary:

- I provided a "covering index" with the columns in the right order to allow finding the 50 ids directly from that index.
- The rest of the work is limited to the 50 rows (or sets of rows, since I suspect that the rest are many:1 with respect to `invoices`.)
- Your `EXPLAIN` shows lots of "Rows" and a "filesort" -- indicating that it gathered everything, then did the group by, then sorted, and finally, peeled of 50.
- I suspect the "filesort" was really two sorts.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON ...` to find out.

Comment: your method much faster,It cost 0.015sec. But you put limit 50 in sub sql,So I cant use where case to filter other table(ii,it) , where ii.variant_id = '1234' or where it.payment_id > 4

Comment: @apple_w - Sorry, I optimized what you presented.  If you would like advice on variations on that query, please provide the exact text of them.  Alas, I may not be able to make it as fast.